# $\exists M >0$ s.d. $ \vert R(z)\vert \leq \frac{M}{x^2}$, calculation of integral with the residue theorem

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, residue-calculus

Given a polynomial of the form $R(z):=\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$ such that $R(z)$ has no real roots and $deg(Q) \geq deg(P) + 2$, then the integral can be expressed as

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} R(z)dz=2\pi i\sum_{a \in \Bbb H}{\mathrm{Res}\left ( f;a \right )}$$
where $\Bbb H:=\{z \in \Bbb C: Im(z)>0\}$.

Now for proving this statement, we have first to show that the following limit exists:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} R(z)dz=\lim_{r \to -\infty}\int_{r}^{+\infty} R(z)dz+\lim_{r \to +\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{r} R(z)dz$$
The argument they used there, is that $\exists M >0$ s.d. $ \vert R(z)\vert \leq \frac{M}{x^2}$. But I don't see, why it exists such an $M$. Many thanks for some help!

Answer (score 1):

$z^{2} \frac {a_0+a_1z+...+a_nz^{n}} {b_0+b_1z+...+b_mz^{m}}$ tends to $0$ if $m >n+2$ and it tends to $\frac {a_n} {b_n}$ if $m=n+2$. Hence $z^{2} \frac {a_0+a_1z+...+a_nz^{n}} {b_0+b_1z+...+b_mz^{m}}$ is a bounded function.

[Since $x^{2}R(x)$ is continuous on the real line and has finite limits at $\pm \infty$ it is a bounded function].

Comment: $x^2R(x)$ is cont. bc it is integrable?

Comment: @FrederickManfred It is a ratio of two continuous functions in which the denominator does not vanish.

Comment: Thank you, I got it

Comment: Just one question, we have that it tends to 0 if $z^{n+2}<z^m$ but this means $n+2<m$, not?

Comment: @FrederickManfred To see that it tends to $0$ divide all the terms in numerator and denominator by $z^{m}$. In the numerator each term tends to $0$ but  the denominator tends a non-zero constant.

Answer (score 1):

The function $x\mapsto x^2R(x)=\frac{x^2P(x)}{Q(x)}$ is a rational function such that the degree of the numerator is smaller than or equal to the degree of the denominator, and therfore the limits $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\frac{x^2P(x)}{Q(x)}$ exist and are real numbers. So, that function is bounded and now you can take $M$ such that $(\forall x\in\Bbb R):\left|\frac{x^2P(x)}{Q(x)}\right|\leqslant M$, and then $(\forall x\in\Bbb R):\left|R(x)\right|\leqslant\frac M{x^2}$.